# How can I return my count integer to main from my function?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, parameters, parameter-passing

I'm pretty new to programming and trying to get this project to return a value to main from the function, however i'm a bit sketchy on passing data and the formatting.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace most_frequent_int
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            mostFreq(new int[] {1,5,2,5,24,6,5});
        }

        static void mostFreq(int[] number)
        {
            int element = 0;
            int count = 0;

            for (int j = 0; j < number.Length; j++)
            {
                int tempElement = number[j];
                int tempCount = 0;

                for (int p = 0; p <number.Length; p++)
                {
                    if (number[p] == tempElement)
                    {
                        tempCount++;
                    }
                    if (tempCount > count)
                        element = tempElement;
                    {
                        count = tempCount;
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("The most frequent element is: " + element + " and appears " + count + " times.");
        }

    }
}
```

I'm trying to take the value stored in count in the method and return it to main to be used again there, but i'm racking my head on how to do so.
Really sorry if this is a completely stupid question but any help is appreciated.

Comment: change `static void mostFreq` into `static int mostFreq` and at the end of the method put `return count;` to return the value. you also have to store the returned value. so write this when calling your method.  `int count = mostFreq(new int[] {1,5,2,5,24,6,5}); `

Answer (score 2):

First change the return type of your method to what you want: (an integer)

```
static int mostFreq(int[] number)
{
    //...
}
```

In your mostFreq method, use the return keyword to pass the value you need to return that way:

```
static int mostFreq(int[] number)
{
    //...
    return count;
}
```

Then catch the value in main and use it:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int count = mostFreq(new int[] {1,5,2,5,24,6,5});
    Console.WriteLine("Count is " + count);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to communicate from a function to its caller is probably just to return the value, such as with the following example:

```
static int return42() {
    return 42;
}
```

And then, in `main`:

```
int fortytwo = return42();
```

In other words, it entails:

- ensuring the function signature returns a real type rather than `void`;
- actually returning the desired value from the function; and
- having the caller pick up the return value for later use.

Unfortunately, you have *two* values you wish to return. While you *could* return the string itself and just print it in `main`, it doesn't really give you the adaptability if you want to use the count and value in other ways, from other pieces of code.

That is, after all, the main reason for putting things into functions, so that common code can be called from many places.

A more adaptable way could use a number of options, such as:

- using tuples, which are a class containing multiple objects;
- returning an array if the variables are of the same type; or
- using `out` parameters in the function for secondary return values.

Using that last one, for example, would entail something like (with your actual code replaced with some magic function calls for demo purposes):

```
static void mostFreq(int[] number, [out] int value) {
    value = MagicMostCommonValueInArray();
    return MagicCountOfThatValue();
}
```

And then, in `main`:

```
int element;
int count = mostFreq(new int[] {1,5,2,5,24,6,5}, out element);
Console.WriteLine(
    "The most frequent element is: " + element +
    " and appears " + count + " times.");
```

My advice would be to use that method rather than returning a single string.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace most_frequent_int
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string result = mostFreq(new int[] {1,5,2,5,24,6,5});
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }

    static string mostFreq(int[] number)
    {
        int element = 0;
        int count = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < number.Length; j++)
        {
            int tempElement = number[j];
            int tempCount = 0;

            for (int p = 0; p <number.Length; p++)
            {
                if (number[p] == tempElement)
                {
                    tempCount++;
                }
                if (tempCount > count)
                    element = tempElement;
                {
                    count = tempCount;
                }
            }
        }
return "The most frequent element is: " + element + " and appears " + count + " times."        
    }

}
```